# What's the point of using @font-face if it looks awful on Windows?

Tags: html, css, font-face, cufon

I used to use @font-face an awful lot (while developing on my mac) and now on PC I see it looks awful.

I've tried searching on stack overflow and I see to make sure hinting is on (it is). It doesn't help at all though.

I hate cufon because it has the burst of unstyled content.

For most professional projects, say sites above $7,000 budget, do you use @font-face and just ignore the fact it looks awful? Or do you use cufon or something else? I have a lot of big projects that need to be perfect in this area.

I understand there are some 'hacks' but it still isn't airtight like it should be.

Thanks

Comment: I just try to use fonts that look alright on Windows.

Comment: You either pick fonts that look good on Windows, or exclude Internet Explorer from the list of browsers in which you display fonts. It is progressive enhancement, and pretty simple to do. Not to mention the amazing effect great typography has on all of the half decent browsers.

Comment: @Tom: Internet Explorer isn't the only Windows browser. Other browsers render fonts very similarly to it on Windows, complete with jaggy edges and very, very bad contours. So the only option... :/

Comment: @BoltClock: I suppose that depends also on the version of Windows that the user has. Chrome 11 on Windows 7 looks pretty dam good in my opinion. There are some hacks for older versions of IE and FF2 for Windows to enable anti-aliasing. You can then just exclude fonts from Windows in general.

Comment: Remember that all font rendering on Windows looks bad – users who have only used Windows are unlikely to notice, as if they felt that reading text was important, they'd use a different OS!

Answer (score 0):

In this regard, the only thing you can do is test extensively.

Pick fonts that look decent at various sizes and test on PCs.  There are a number of decent fonts that are compatible.

Also, consider using the Google Fonts api.  Their stuff renders pretty well: http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/

Font Squirrel has decent fonts too: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ On their site, they have a view function that allows you to test it.